# Solving for the coefficients of a series

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion

Suppose I have a given series $A(z)=\Sigma a_nz^n$

I want to solve a differential equation for $B(z)$ in terms of coefficients of $a_n$ as a series. Possibly with ansatz $B(z)=\Sigma b_nz^n$ or other form.

In other words, I want to get $b_n$ in terms of $a_n$.

My equation is this $\frac{dB}{dz}=-z(A+B)(B+1)$

How do I let Mathematica to do this for me?

So far I have tried defining the series using `Sum` and `SolveAlways`.

But it seems completely wrong. And I believe there must be a good way of doing this on Mathematica.

Additional question:

```
ord = 3;
mzi = M - Exp[-z]*(Sum[a[n] (1/z)^n, {n, 0, ord}] + O[z]^(ord + 1));
pzi = Exp[-z]*(Sum[p[n] (1/z)^n, {n, 0, ord}] + O[z]^(ord + 1));
With[{mzii = mzi, pzii = pzi}, 
SolveAlways[D[pzii, z] == -\[Epsilon]^2/z^2 (D[mzii, z]/(4 Pi*z^2) + pzii) 
(4*Pi*z^3*pzii + mzii), z]]
```

And I want to solve for `p[n]` in terms of `a[n]`, but I get an error message saying: not a polynomial.

Comment: You were right to start with `Sum[]` + `SolveAlways[]`: `With[{af = Sum[a[n] z^n, {n, 0, 12}] + O[z]^13, bf = Sum[b[n] z^n, {n, 0, 12}] + O[z]^13}, SolveAlways[D[bf, z] == -z (af + bf) (bf + 1), z]]`

Comment: @J.M. This code worked well on the first part. Then I tried to see the behavior when z goes to infinity. Here i my code                                          ord = 3;
mzi = M - Exp[-z]*(Sum[a[n] (1/z)^n, {n, 0, ord}] + O[z]^(ord + 1));
pzi = Exp[-z]*(Sum[p[n] (1/z)^n, {n, 0, ord}] + O[z]^(ord + 1));
With[{mzii = mzi, pzii = pzi}, 
 SolveAlways[
  D[pzii, z] == -\[Epsilon]^2/
     z^2 (D[mzii, z]/(4 Pi*z^2) + pzii) (4*Pi*z^3*pzii + mzii), z]]                                     Then I want to solve p[n] in terms of a[n]. This gives me error...

Comment: "Then I tried to see the behavior when z goes to infinity." - why didn't you put this in the question to begin with?

Comment: @J.M. I had to examine both cases... sorry

Comment: Then, please edit your question.

Comment: Okay... first, you can specify the expansion point in `O[]`; since you're looking at asymptotic series, try `O[z, ∞]^(ord + 1)`. Second, you might want to do a little simplification first and see if you can reformulate to avoid the exponential factor; that messes `SolveAlways[]` up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
With[{s = Series[B'[z] == -z (A[z] + B[z]) (B[z] + 1), {z, 0, 4}]},
    First @ Solve[s, Union @ Cases[s, Derivative[_][B][0], Infinity]]
] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{B'(0)\to 0,B''(0)\to -(B(0)+1) (A(0)+B(0)),B^{(3)}(0)\to -2 (B(0)+1) A'(0),B^{(4)}(0)\to 3
>    (B(0)+1) \left(-A''(0)+3 A(0) B(0)+A(0)^2+A(0)+2 B(0)^2+B(0)\right),B^{(5)}(0)\to 4 (B(0)+1)
>    \left(-A^{(3)}(0)+7 B(0) A'(0)+5 A(0) A'(0)+2 A'(0)\right)\right\}$

I didn't solve for `B[0]` because the ODE doesn't specify a value for it.

Comment: Thank you, but what should I do if I want to expand the series at other z (e.g., 1, 2, or infinity), rather than z=0?